# Get field value using LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to get the value of the fee in this linq query and pass it to another controller.

I tried this

```
var fee = from f in db.Certificates
          where f.ID == traveler.CertificateID && f.Fee>0
          select f.Fee;
int q = fee.Count();
string famount = fee.ToString();
if (q > 0)
{
  TempData["famount"] = famount;
}
```

But it passes the sql statement. something simple but i am trying to save some time.

Comment: which value? your query may return more than one value.

Comment: Is it matter to add data to TempData ony in case if count of fee data is more than zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fee is IQueryable and you have to use `FirstOrDefault()` to get value

```
var fee = from f in db.Certificates
          where f.ID == traveler.CertificateID && f.Fee>0
          select f.Fee;

string famount = fee.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting a collection in your query. `select f.Fee` would return `IQueryable<T>`/`IEnumerable<T>`.

It appears that since you are selecting based on `ID`, you should get a **single** result back. Use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like:

```
var fee = (from f in db.Certificates
            where f.ID == traveler.CertificateID && f.Fee>0
            select f.Fee).SingleOrDefault();

if (fee != null)
{
    TempData["famount"] = fee;
}
```

You can also pass the condition in `SingleOrDefault` like:

```
var fee = db.Certificates.SingleOrDefault(f => traveler.CertificateID && f.Fee > 0);
```

`SingleOrDefault` would throw an exception if more than one item is found matching the criteria. If that is the case *(and you are not selecting on unique ID)* then use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Why to initiate two or more variables?

```
TempData["famount"] = db.Certificates.Where(f=>f.ID == traveler.CertificateID && f.Fee>0).FirstOrDefault.Count();
```